# actorからwebsocketのbroadcastをするには

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

playでactorから接続しているクライアントにbroadcastするにはどうしたらよいですか？

playでwebsocketを使うときの参考になるサイトがあったらぜひ教えて下さい。

```
//Global.scala
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    val system = ActorSystem("system")
    val hello = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], "HelloActor")
    hello ! "world"
  }

}

//HelloActor.scala
class HelloActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "world" => helloWorld
  }

  def helloWorld = {
    val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
    channel.push("HelloWorld!!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControllerにBroadcast用のデータのレシーバーを用意して、データを受信したらBroadcastするようにして解決しました。

```
//Application.scala
object Application extends Controller {

  var channel: MutableList[Concurrent.Channel[String]] = MutableList()

  def socket = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
    val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
    val out = Concurrent.unicast[String]{ c => channel += c }
    (in, out)
  }

  def reciever = Action { request =>
    channel.foreach(_.push(request.body.asJson.toString))
    Ok("success!")
  }
}


//HelloActor.scala
class HelloActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case "Hello" => WS.url(url+"/product/info").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "text/plain").post("Hello!")
        case _ =>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-iteratees

上のドキュメントにあるように下記のような方法でどうでしょうか？

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

def socket =  WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

  // Concurrent.broadcast returns (Enumerator, Concurrent.Channel)
  val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]

  // log the message to stdout and send response back to client
  val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
    msg => println(msg)
      // the Enumerator returned by Concurrent.broadcast subscribes to the channel and will
      // receive the pushed messages
      channel push("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
  (in,out)
}
```

Comment: 追記したように書いたのですが、actorとplayのcontextは別？なのかうまく行きません。実際の処理はActorをスケジュールで動かして、定期的に接続しているクライアントにデータを送信する、というものにしたいと思っております。

Comment: なるほど。そうすると、スケジューリングされて動いている Actor と WebSocket で接続されてる Actor は別のインスタンスになっているということですよね？

Comment: はい。そういう解釈であってます。

Comment: コンテキストが同じであれば actorSelection でブロードキャストできますが、 「Actorをスケジュールで動かし」てる動かし方によっては、 WebSocket の Actor とスケジュールで動いている Actor が別コンテキストになっていると思うので、工夫しないといけないです。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: @KoyaFukushi おめでとうございます！